# Read Strings from a file and putting them into an array in build.gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a file that contains list of paths `paths.list`

```
current/path/to/hai
current/path/to/hai2
path/to/hai3
path/to/hai4
```

I want to read this file and place these paths in `srcDirs` list

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir = ['current/path/to/hai','current/path/to/hai2','path/to/hai3','path/to/hai4']
        }
    }
}
```

I have several paths to be added in the list

How to read these paths from list so that they get reflected in `scrDir` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def srcDirs = file('paths.list').text.readLines()
srcDirs.each { srcDirectory ->
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir srcDirectory
            }
        }
    }
}
```